# How to add ggplot legend of two different lines R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I need to add a legend of the two lines (best fit line and 45 degree line) on TOP of my two plots. Sorry I don't know how to add plots! Please please please help me, I really appreciate it!!!!

Here is an example

```
type=factor(rep(c("A","B","C"),5))
xvariable=seq(1,15)
yvariable=2*xvariable+rnorm(15,0,2)
newdata=data.frame(type,xvariable,yvariable)
p = ggplot(newdata,aes(x=xvariable,y=yvariable))
p+geom_point(size=3)+ facet_wrap(~ type) +
  geom_abline(intercept =0, slope =1,color="red",size=1)+ 
  stat_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE,size=1)
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is another approach which uses aesthetic mapping to string constants to identify different groups and create a legend.

First an alternate way to create your test data (and naming it `DF` instead of `newdata`)

```
DF <- data.frame(type = factor(rep(c("A", "B", "C"), 5)),
                 xvariable = 1:15,
                 yvariable = 2 * (1:15) + rnorm(15, 0, 2))
```

Now the `ggplot` code. Note that for both `geom_abline` and `stat_smooth`, the `colour` is set inside and `aes` call which means each of the two values used will be mapped to a different color and a guide (legend) will be created for that mapping.

```
ggplot(DF, aes(x = xvariable, y = yvariable)) +
  geom_point(size = 3) + 
  geom_abline(aes(colour="one-to-one"), intercept =0, slope = 1, size = 1) +
  stat_smooth(aes(colour="best fit"), method = "lm", se = FALSE, size = 1) + 
  facet_wrap(~ type) +
  scale_colour_discrete("")
```

[image]

Comment: @Henrik Often when an aesthetic is mapped to a string constant, it is an error on the users part because the intent was to set, not map, the aesthetic. But here a mapping is really what is desired.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
# original data
type <- factor(rep(c("A", "B", "C"), 5))
x <- 1:15
y <- 2 * x + rnorm(15, 0, 2)

df <- data.frame(type, x, y)

# create a copy of original data, but set y = x
# this data will be used for the one-to-one line
df2 <- data.frame(type, x, y = x)

# bind original and 'one-to-one data' together
df3 <- rbind.data.frame(df, df2)

# create a grouping variable to separate stat_smoothers based on original and one-to-one data 
df3$grp <- as.factor(rep(1:2, each = nrow(df)))

# plot
# use original data for points
# use 'double data' for abline and one-to-one line, set colours by group
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  facet_wrap(~ type) +
  stat_smooth(data = df3, aes(colour = grp), method = "lm", se = FALSE, size = 1) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("red","blue"),
                      labels = c("abline", "one-to-one"),
                      name = "") +
  theme(legend.position = "top")

# If you rather want to stack the two keys in the legend you can add:
# guide = guide_legend(direction = "vertical")
#...as argument in scale_colour_manual
```

Please note that this solution does not extrapolate the one-to-one line outside the range of your data, which seemed to be the case for the original `geom_abline`.
[image]